# How to implement promise when updating a state in functional React (when using useState hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, promise, state

I know similar questions are bouncing around the web for quite some time but I still struggle to find a decision for my case.

Now I use functional React with hooks. What I need in this case is to set a state and AFTER the state was set THEN to start the next block of code, maybe like React with classes works:

```
this.setState({
   someStateFlag: true
}, () => { // then:
   this.someMethod(); // start this method AFTER someStateFlag was updated
});
```

Here I have created a playground sandbox that demonstrates the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/alertdialog-demo-material-ui-forked-6zss6q?file=/demo.tsx

Please push the button to get the confirmation dialog opened. Then confirm with "YES!" and notice the lag. This lag occurs because the loading data method starts before the close dialog flag in state was updated.

```
const fireTask = () => {
   setOpen(false); // async
   setResult(fetchHugeData()); // starts immediately
};
```

What I need to achieve is maybe something like using a promise:

```
const fireTask = () => {
   setOpen(false).then(() => {
      setResult(fetchHugeData());
   });
};
```

Because the order in my case is important. I need to have dialog closed first (to avoid the lag) and then get the method fired.

And by the way, what would be your approach to implement a loading effect with MUI Backdrop and CircularProgress in this app?

Comment: Re. the "waiting for state to change first", you can use an effect with the state value as a dependency. This will run the code _after_ the state changes and the component renders with said new state value.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to resolve the task. Now publishing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `this.setState` callback alternative for React hooks is basically the `useEffect` hook.
It is a "built-in" React hook which accepts a callback as it's first parameter and then runs it every time the value of any of it's dependencies changes.
The second argument for the hook is the array of dependencies.

**Example:**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const fireTask = () => {
   setOpen(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
   if (open) {
      return;
   }
   setResult(fetchHugeData());
}, [open]);
```

In other words, `setResult` would run every time the value of `open` changes,
and only after it has finished changing and a render has occurred.

We use a simple `if` statement to allow our code to run only when `open` is `false`.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info.

Comment: I think I understand useEffect() and useCallback() well and use them often but are they applicable in this case? 1. I don't want to fire fetchHugeData() method initially - it must be fired only from the confirmation dialog. 2. I must avoid the lag after "YES!" was pushed. Could you try to apply a fix to a copy of my sandbox? I just didn't manage to achieve a good result with useEffect().

Comment: in fact I managed to resolve the task with additional dependency. I will publish it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, looking forward to see what you came up with, I was just playing around with the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to resolve the problem with additional dependency in state:

https://codesandbox.io/s/alertdialog-demo-material-ui-forked-gevciu?file=/demo.tsx

Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to see if we can avoid adding additional `state` for this. It feels like it should be simpler. I'll comment if I find a good approach.

Comment: If we **really** want to avoid the lag, one way to go about this would be to use `setTimeout` with 0ms. It's rather hacky, but what it essentially does is wait for the render cycle to finish before executing the code. It also removes the need for the additional `state`. https://codesandbox.io/s/alertdialog-demo-material-ui-forked-yr0ubj?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Re: "one way to go about this would be to use setTimeout with 0ms": Nope. It doesn't wait but rather forces extra re-rendering (after some flush I guess). Not a good idea.

Comment: WDYM? have you checked out the provided codesandbox link? I've created an example and it seems to work as you described it should.

Comment: Maybe yes, looks like it works correctly. Thank you for this help.